# update mongo mongo 2.11.0 to 3.2.0 with spring-data-mongodb 1.0.0.M2 with not finding com.mongodb.DB.isAuthenticated()Z

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

With Spring version - 3.0.5.RELEASE.
I am updating mongo 2.11.0 to 3.2.0 and getting NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.DB.isAuthenticated()Z

1. I can't change spring version
2. So I can't change spring-data-mongodb version

   ```
   private MongoTemplate getNewTemplate() {


   MongoTemplate template = null;
   try {


       Mongo mongo = new Mongo(host, port);


       List<Converter<?,?>> converters = new ArrayList<Converter<?,?>>();
       converters.add((Converter) new BigDecimalToDoubleConverter());
       converters.add((Converter) new DoubleToBigDecimalConverter());

       MongoMappingContext mappingContext = new MongoMappingContext();
       mappingContext.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationContext);
       MappingMongoConverter mmc = new MappingMongoConverter(mappingContext);

       mmc.setConverters(converters);
       mmc.setMongo(mongo);

       mmc.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

       template = new MongoTemplate(mongo, dbName, "versionchangevalue", mmc);
       template.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationContext);
       template.setMappingContext(mappingContext);
       template.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED);

        mmc.afterPropertiesSet();

       if ((username != null) && !(username.isEmpty())) {
           template.setUsername(username);
           template.setPassword(password); 
       }



   } catch (Exception e) {
       logger.error("Fatal error connecting to mongo db. Host not found for hostname:port=" + host + ":" + port, e);
   }


   return template;
   }
   }
   ```

**Working version**

```
{   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>
}
```

Giving **Error**

> NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.DB.isAuthenticated()Z

when changing to

```
{

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what are the reasons behind this upgrade ? Its a major version change. It won't be really useful if you can't udpate the spring data mongo version that goes with that mongo driver version.

Comment: Yes I know ideal would be to change spring version as well. But Architectural decision has been made that spring version won't be changed in this release. We upgrade only mongo version. I did try with 2.14.0-rc0 mongo-java-driver but then I have other issue as - org.springframework.data.document.UncategorizedDocumentStoreException: "errmsg" : "not authorized on "UAT" to execute command

Answer (score 0):

Support for the MongoDB Java driver 3.x line has been added with `RC1` of Spring Data MongoDB 1.7 (Fowler). Pls. see [DATAMONGO-1158](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1158) for details.

Using a milestone from 2011 will not allow you to use any more recent MongoDB Java driver.

Comment: I agree we will soon change it. Priority was to make minimal changes so that trick worked for me. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me as mongo java driver 2.14.* supports mongodb 3.2

```
        <!-- mongodb java driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```